# Lebesgue points

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Lebesgue points are defined by:
$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{Leb(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|dy=0 \text{ for a.e. } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ w.r.t. } Leb$$

where $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}), B(x,r)$ is the ball with center $x$ and radius $r$.

My question is: if we replace $Leb$ by general measure $\mu$? Do we still have the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are results of the type you mention for Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. There are analytic methods (Besicovitch's coverings, Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequalities) to approach them as well as probabilistic methods (Martingales). Here is one such result:

**Theorem:**

Suppose $\nu$ and $\mu$ are Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mu\geq0$. Let
\begin{aligned}
 \lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{\nu(\overline{B(x;r)})}{\mu(\overline{B(x;r)})}=D_\mu\nu(x)
\end{aligned}

Suppose the Radon--Nikodym decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ is
\begin{aligned}
    \nu=\nu_a+\nu_\perp =\frac{d\nu_a}{d\mu}\cdot\mu + \nu_\perp
  \end{aligned}
be the Radon--Nikodym decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. Then

(i). $D_\mu\nu_a$ exists $\mu$--a.s. and
\begin{aligned}
   f= \frac{d\nu_a}{d\mu}= D_\mu\nu = D_\mu\nu_a \qquad \text{$\mu$--a.s.},
  \end{aligned}
and for $\mu$--a.a. $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$,
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\mu\big(\overline{B(x;r)}\big)}\int_{\overline{B(x;r)}}|f(y)-f(x)|\,\mu(dy).
  \end{aligned}
(ii). $D_\mu\nu_\perp$ exists $\mu$--a.s. and
\begin{align}
    D_\mu\nu_\perp=0\qquad\text{$\mu$--a.s.}
  \end{align}

---

Comment: Thanks! Could you pls tell me what is the name of this theorem? where can I find its proof?

Comment: Also, you mention maximal inequality as the tool for the proof. This reminds me that it requires the measure should have a double property, that is, $\mu(B(x,r))  \approx \mu(B(x,2r))$, which plays a crucial role in Vitali covering. That is why I doubted that not all $\mu$ has full measure Leb points.

Comment: From the analysis point of view, the book of Evans and Gariepy, Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, has on derivatives on Radon measures (section 1.6, chapter 1). The book of Frank Jones, Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean space (Chapter 15) has a gentler presentation too. From the point of view of Probability, the book of Doob (Stochastic processes (Supplement 2), Durrent's book Probability Theory also deals with differentiation of measure ih his chapter on Martingales. Meine and Tweedie's book on Markov Chains also has a realty discussion on differentiation of measures.

Comment: Thanks for the references!